# Create SQL procedures in while-loop with procedure-name as variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, procedure

is there a way to create a list of procedures via a while-loop in SQL?

What im trying to do is something like this, but with a much bigger attribute-table.

```
Declare @attributes Table (attrkey text, attr_key text)
  Insert @attributes(attrkey, attr_key) values('userFirstName',  'user_first_name')
  Insert @attributes(attrkey, attr_key) values('userFamilyName', 'user_family_name')
  Insert @attributes(attrkey, attr_key) values('userNameExtra',  'user_name_extra')

Declare @attrkey nvarchar(128)
Declare @attr_key nvarchar(128)
Declare @proc_name_set nvarchar(128)
Declare @proc_name_del nvarchar(128)


While exists (Select * From @attributes)
  Begin
    Select @attrkey = attrkey, @attr_key = attr_key from @attributes
    Set @proc_name_set = 'set_web_user_' + @attr_key
    Set @proc_name_del = 'del_web_user_' + @attr_key

    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[@proc_name_set] @keyval int, @value nvarchar(255)  AS
    UPDATE web_user SET @attrkey=@value WHERE id=@keyval;
    Go
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[@proc_name_del] @keyval int, @value nvarchar(255)  AS
    UPDATE web_user SET @attrkey=NULL WHERE id=@keyval AND @attrkey=@value;
    Go

    Delete from @attributes where attrkey like @attrkey
  End
```

Comment: add tag for specific language. mysql, oracle, ms sql, postgres ...
According to your question. You can do that with dynamic sql. There is no way to do that in the plain sql

Comment: you should not use variables like that, that should be assigned to some other variable(let as **@sql**)and execute it using **exec**  or **sp_execute sql** as **EXEC(@sql)**

Comment: You may have more joy if your loop builds a string with the CREATE PROCEDURE Statements in it, the use `sp_execute_sql` to run that dynamic sql.  But I've never tried to create a procedure from within a procedure before.  It feels like a bit of a broken design pattern to me.  Why are you doing this, what is the functional requirement?

Comment: you mean to store the create-part in a string and than use EXEC?

Comment: Yes, the whole CREATE PROCEDURE statement to be in a string variable, then execute that string using `sp_execute_sql`

Comment: @MatBailie Im trying to setup an LDAP with custom schema using mssql as back-db. The LDAP uses these procedures to set or delete attributes, so I need to create them ones.

Comment: Can't you create one SP that takes the attribute as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

While there might be better ways of doing this I guess it might be a one time operation and performance might not matter much. If so then this modified code should work and create a `set_web_user_` and `del_web_user_` procedure for all attributes:

```
Declare @attributes Table (attrkey text, attr_key text)
Insert @attributes(attrkey, attr_key) values('userFirstName',  'user_first_name')
Insert @attributes(attrkey, attr_key) values('userFamilyName', 'user_family_name')
Insert @attributes(attrkey, attr_key) values('userNameExtra',  'user_name_extra')

Declare @attrkey nvarchar(128)
Declare @attr_key nvarchar(128)
Declare @proc_name_set nvarchar(128)
Declare @proc_name_del nvarchar(128)
Declare @proc_text nvarchar(max)

While exists (Select * From @attributes)
  Begin
    Select @attrkey = attrkey, @attr_key = attr_key from @attributes
    Set @proc_name_set = 'set_web_user_' + @attr_key
    Set @proc_name_del = 'del_web_user_' + @attr_key

    Set @proc_text = N'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[' + @proc_name_set + '] @keyval int, @value nvarchar(255)  AS
    UPDATE web_user SET ' + @attrkey + ' = @value WHERE id = @keyval;'

    EXEC sp_executesql @proc_text

    Set @proc_text = N'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[' + @proc_name_del + '] @keyval int, @value nvarchar(255)  AS
    UPDATE web_user SET ' + @attrkey + ' = NULL WHERE id = @keyval AND ' + @attrkey + ' = @value;'

    EXEC sp_executesql @proc_text

    Delete from @attributes where attrkey like @attrkey
  End
```